# Tapping on a post opens the web viewer

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

As the title. The changelog doesn't say anything about this... Just that there could be breaking.

- App Version: 1.6.0
- Device: iPhone 4S
- OS Version: Version 9.3.5 (Build 13G36)

Comment: Can you describe your exact steps to reproduce this?

Comment: @BrianNickel tapping on a comment notification, a post in the question list, an answer, an entry that links to a post in the achievement list, will produce the buggy behavior. Not sure if there's something else. I just switched from beta to release and then beta again.

Comment: I've been able to reproduce this.  I'll be pushing out a fix on Monday.

Comment: @BrianNickel is any different the repro steps?

Comment: The only specific thing I had to do for repro was find my iPhone 4S.  I know what system would be triggering this, but have no idea why yet.  Haven't seen it on other devices.

Comment: @Brian I have this problem on my 5C.  The web viewer opens when I try to view on any post, user, or tag.

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in 1.6.0.1.

It was caused by sloppiness on my part, though I really wish the compiler had warned me.  In 1.6, I reworked the way view controllers are dispatched in the app.  When you tap on a question, the question URL is posted as an intent and different handlers attempt to resolve it.  The question handler, includes the following checks (simplified):

```
- (BOOL)canHandleIntent:(SEUIIntent *)intent withSender:(id)sender
{
    return [SEQuestionLocation locationWithURL:intent.URL error:NULL] != nil
        && [self canHandleIntentWithSender:sender];
}

- (BOOL)canHandleIntentWithSender:(id)sender
{
    return [self navigationControllerForSender:sender];
}

- (UINavigationController *)navigationControllerForSender:(id)sender
{
    ...
}
```

The first check worked fine everywhere, the URL could be parsed.  The second check, `[self canHandleIntentWithSender:sender]` consistently failed only on 32-bit machines.

The problem is that the compiler is implicitly casting a pointer to a `BOOL`, [on 32-bit machines `BOOL` is typecast to `signed char`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/544250/860000), and the pointer is aligned such that the least significant byte is always zero.  On 64-bit machines, `BOOL` is typecast to `bool` which properly converts the non-zero value to `true`:

> ```
> (lldb) p (signed char)0x100
> (signed char) $7 = '\0'
> (lldb) p (bool)0x100
> (bool) $8 = true
> ```

The fix is straight-forward and would not have been an issue had I written the thing in Swift in the first place:

```
- (BOOL)canHandleIntentWithSender:(id)sender
{
    return [self navigationControllerForSender:sender] != nil;
}
```